# How to filter out html tags using sed and regex

Tags: bash, sed

I have a script that needs to filter out the html tags from two different texts using one regular expression. The reason I need one regex is that the data being passed to the script could potentially be in either of the text formats. The text generally have the same syntax except for a few differences

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

text1="<CENTER><B>Jupiter: The Great Yellow Spot<BR>"
text2="<b> Curiosity Rover Finds a Clay Cache on Mars </b> <br> "

regex="s|.*<b>\(.*\)<b.*|\1|I"

some_text1=$(echo $text1 | sed $regex)
some_text2=$(echo $text2 | sed $regex)

echo $some_text1
echo $some_text2
```

The code works perfectly for text1 but leaves a `</b>` in text2.

Output:

```
Jupiter: The Great Yellow Spot
Curiosity Rover Finds a Clay Cache on Mars </b>
```

How can I ensure that it removes all the html tags?

Comment: [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not). `sed $regex` is very unsafe, remember to quote your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all substrings starting from `<` up until the next `>`, you could:

Replace all occurences of `<` followed by a number of characters different then `>` and a `>` by nothing.

Which in sed is:

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

This will not remove tags that span multiple lines. To do that, you could use GNU sed extension `-z` option.

Comment: Thanks so much I hadn't considered this